# Edge line appear in render result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I want to create an environment texture from a cube map, so I create a cube then map the textures like this: 
[image: Cube map]

But inside the cube, where I put the camera, I can see a black line at the edge's position.

[image: Edge line]

After render, this line is visible at final result too.

[image: The line at the result texture]

volvis told me to change mapping mode, but I use Cycles Render, so I can not find where is mapping node setting.

[image: Texture setting]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wager that this is caused by the image mapping. Textures are set to repeat by default, and the dark line looks like the bottom part of the texture bleeding to view. Try changing the image mapping mode to Extend or similar and see if that works for you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I use Cycles Render, so I can not find the mapping node like you said. I have added my texture setting screenshot into the question.

Comment: Ah, true, Cycles seems to be missing those options. I'd consider switching to Blender Internal for this one time. Your other option would be to scale the UVs down one tiny smidge - just enough to hide the tiling artifact - but you'll lose some image data in the process.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! It lose some image data like you said, but it's very hard to notice (not visible like the black line).